# Why did democracy emerge in what is now Greece?

Tags: democracy

I suppose we can't know the answer to this question, but I think it's worth hearing other people's best guesses. My theory is that Greece is special because it’s mostly comprised of many small islands. Expanding a kingdom from one island to two is much more difficult than expanding a kingdom on land. Each island had its most powerful family and it would have been [more] natural for them to see each other as rough equals. Democracy would have been an obvious government type when the islands needed to make a collective decision.

Comment: Much speculation - few facts and no references.  Our goal is to compose definitive answers, and that all analysis be backed up by evidence. As Democracy developed on mainland Greece and not the Aegean archipelago, I see no particular merit to this *analysis* as presented.

Comment: This is the kind of info I was looking for. Thanks Peter

Answer (score 2):

Each of the Greek city states had its own constitution. Some had kings, others were ruled by an aristocratic oligarchy. Democracy (in the original Greek sense of the term) was basically  limited to Athens. It is not true that Greece was “mostly comprised of many small islands”; Athens in any case is not an island. So your linkage of democracy and islands does not really have anything in its favour.

Comment: Other cities had democracy too. For example, Argos or Megara. We just know a lot more about Athens.

Comment: That is why I said "basically".

Comment: I don't want to nitpick but your usage seems to imply that democracy outsie of Athens was a marginal or insignificant phenomenon. This is not so. Starting from the 7th century many cities were democratic during some or all of their history. The tug of war between democracy and oligarchy is an important part of Thucydides's story - which would not have been so were democracy marginal.

Comment: Did they have a written constitution, or are you saying that each had distinct governance?

Comment: An unwritten constitution, as in Britain even today.

Answer (score -1):

It didn't, that kind of tribal "democracy" isn't special to Greece. Lots of tribes make collective deicisions in a more or less democratic way. Greek democracy excludes most of the population who arent citizens. That's not different from other societies where only the priviledged caste can participate in government. Greece is just remembered specially today because it was the inspiration when real modern democracy was being setup in the last few centuries.

Comment: Im pointing out the premise was flawed

Comment: So you think ancient Greece was really democratic? Its not.

Comment: if you dont like my answer go away and make your own. my answer is the op's wrong about greece being special and democracy didn't start there

Comment: I am afraid I have to downvote: Greek democracy *was* special. The notion of the entire (male, adult, unenslaved) population participating in government and making the laws is not something that's found in tribes. Try coming up with examples form elsewhere and you'll see how special that was. (I've once read that Indian villages had something similar - but on a much smaller scale, so that might be one small example). The fact that by modern standards the Greek poleis were very bigoted (against women and slaves, chiefly) should not blind us to their being a real huge step furward in history.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg ancient india had democracies if we dont count the lowest castes, in the same way you exclud greek slaves. Germanic tribes practiced direct democracies. New zealand Maories had tribe meetings where heads of households could speak about big issues like the Greek forums

Comment: @CrèmeCaramelita: can you give some details about the Māori practice? There's a big difference between "everyone gets to have a few words" and "everyone gets a single vote *and the outcome is binding.*" Another culture would be even better, actually, since the Māori settled New Zealand ~2,000 years after Athens.